# this.setState not updating state

Tags: reactjs, antd

For some reason my `this.state` call is not updating the state in my `roleClicked` function. I can't seem to figure out what the problem is. Here is the code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import instance from '../../../config/axios';
import ls from 'local-storage';
import Sidenav from '../../layout/Sidenav'
import isLoggedIn from '../../../helpers/isLoggedIn';
import redirectToLogin from '../../../helpers/redirectToLogin';
import apiErrorHandler from '../../../helpers/apiErrorHandler';
import RolesHeader from './RolesHeader';
import '../../../App.css'
import { Table, Pagination, Input, Alert } from 'antd';

export default class ViewRoles extends Component {

    state = {
        loggedIn: true,
        roleSelected: false, 
        roleSelectedId: null,
        rolesTable: {
            columns: null,
            dataSource: null,
            currentPageNumber: null,
            currentPageSize: null,
            total: null,
        },
        filters: {
            roleName: null
        },
        displays: {
            createRoleView: false,
            roleCreatedAlert: false,
        },
        errors: null
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
      //here i make AJAX calls to set rolesTables
    } 

    roleClicked = (record) => {
        console.log("clicked")
        this.setState({
            roleSelected: true,
            roleSelectedId: record.key
        })
    }

    render() {

        if(this.state.roleSelected) {
            const roleUrl = "/roles/" + this.state.roleSelectedId
            return <Redirect to={roleUrl}/>
        }

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Sidenav activeLink="roles"/>
                <Table 
                     className="border"
                     columns={this.state.rolesTable.columns} 
                     dataSource={this.state.rolesTable.dataSource} 
                     pagination={false}
                     onRow={(record) => {
                        return {
                           onClick: () => this.roleClicked(record)
                     }}}
                />
                <Pagination 
                    className="m-3"
                    current={this.state.rolesTable.currentPageNumber} 
                    pageSize={this.state.rolesTable.currentPageSize} 
                    total={this.state.rolesTable.total}
                    onChange={this.loadRolesTable}
                />
           </React.Fragment>)
    }
}
```

The function runs as expected but the state is not updated. Any idea what the problem could be?

Everywhere else I use this.setState it works. The full code can be found on this [link](https://quip.com/NAvVATgJTGkI).

Comment: Do you get any result when you invoke this function? Have you tried `console.log(this.state)` after the function call?

Comment: Does `onRow` do the job properly?

Comment: Check whether `record` get passed properly, and it is not undefined

Comment: Also, in the code you linked above, you have `this.setState({ roleSelected: true, roleSelectedId: 1 })`, so no matter how many times you trigger that handler, it will always end up with the same result. Double check that whatever is being passed to `roleClicked` is correct.

Comment: I suspect onRow isn't working properly

Comment: @EvgeniiKlepilin yes I get the full state when I console.log(this.state)

Comment: Also, I get record when I console.log(record) as well. I set roleSelected to 1 while trying to debug just to see if something was wrong with record and it didn't work as well

Comment: I don't think it has to do with onRow. I put the same function in an onClick function on a div and it still didn't update the state. Additionally if I remove the declaration of `roleSelected` and `roleSelectedId` from the state the function works just fine and the state is updated. But if I have them defined as in the code it doesn't work. I can simply remove the declaration and move on but I'm quite interested in why it doesn't work. @chitova263 @goto @EvgeniiKlepilin

Comment: @EvgeniiKlepilin

Comment: Do you get console.log("clicked") back?

Comment: Yes I do @ProttayRudra

Answer (score 1):

I updated roleClicked to this and it works. I still have no idea why the initial code didn't work.

```js
viewRole = async (record) => {
     var currentState = this.state;
     currentState.roleSelected = true;
     currentState.roleSelectedId = record.key;
     await this.setState(currentState);
     console.log(this.state)
}
```

Just changing it to Async didn't work. Only assigning the state to `currentState` and then updating `currentState` and using it in `setState` worked. And now it works both synchronously and asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
    this.setState(function(state, props) {
      return {
        ...state,
        roleSelected: true,
        roleSelectedId: record.key
           };
   });
```

Comment: I did this ```roleClicked = (record) => {
        console.log(record)
        this.setState((state, props) => {
            return {
              roleSelected: true,
              roleSelectedId: record.key}
        })
    }``` still not working.